# How can I pass credentials to SharePoint 2010 people service?

Tags: 2010, web-services, authentication

I need to do a simple request against the People service in SharePoint 2010. Please tell me how I can do that. The following piece doesn't work.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var client = new Backend.PeopleService.PeopleSoapClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\some.user";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "passowrd";
        var people = client.SearchPrincipals("", 1000, SPPrincipalType.All);
    }
```

Error that I get is:

> Test 'M:ShareShare.Tester.Test' failed: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
>       System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Updated on Aug 28, 2012**

So this is what the config file looks like (after setting *security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"* and *transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"*)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="PeopleSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://portal.someserver.com/_vti_bin/People.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PeopleSoap"
            contract="Backend.PeopleService.PeopleSoap" name="PeopleSoap">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now the error is

> Test 'M:ShareShare.Tester.Test' failed: The HTTP request is
>   unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
>     System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
>   request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Updated 2**

I deleted the config file and left just c# code for eliminating one moving part.
So the code looks like this now:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://portal.someserver.com/_vti_bin/People.asmx");


        var client = new Backend.PeopleService.PeopleSoapClient(binding, endpoint);

        var creds = client.ClientCredentials.Windows;
        creds.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
        creds.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("some.user", "password", "domain");
        var people = client.SearchPrincipals("", 1000, SPPrincipalType.All);
    }
```

This still gets me the same error about NTLM (see above).

Comment: see this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/e115f790-fe8a-45e9-982b-21833ea01c7f

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work (with the same exception that I posted in my last updated)

Answer (score 1):

I have used list wcf service. and for that i used following code. it is working for me.

```
     ls = new ListsSoapClient();
     ls.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx");
     ls.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
     ls.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

compare your code with this code and try with this for people service.

follwing is **my config file**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ListsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="409600" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>                
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap" contract="ListColl.ListsSoap"
        name="ListsSoap" />            
</client>
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Your code didn't work either. Although though I tried TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation.

Comment: have u updated your code with referencing this two line also:
ls.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
     ls.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

Comment: Ok, I just tried with the following and I got the same exception:  creds.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            creds.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

Comment: also change in config file as above told you

Comment: Just copied your config over mine and did what you said with the c# part. Still no luck. Same NTLM error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a config change, set:

```
security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"
```

and

```
transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"
```

Should do the trick.

[Update in response]

Try passing your credentials using:

```
service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

I am going to think some more...

Comment: thank you for the advice, it didn't work though, see my update